# How to test multi class/label image classifier?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, multilabel-classification

I am trying to test my image classifier accuracy.
I have only done binary classification and pretty new to deep learning.

I don't really want to do confusion matrix.
I rather want to classify image one by one.

Does anyone have any idea how to test your classifier accuracy one by one with images?
With code snippet would be really helpful

Here's my code

I just did what I usually did in binary classification.
But I am stucked now how to classfy

```
model = load_model('./model.h5')

test_image = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255
)

test_generator = test_image.flow_from_directory(
    './test',
    (32, 32),
    batch_size=20,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=False
)

loss, accuracy = model.evaluate_generator(
    generator=test_generator,
    steps=1
)

labels = test_generator.class_indices
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using TF >= 2.0

You can try this:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image

path = 'path-to-file'
img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(32, 32))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

images = np.vstack([x])
classes = model.predict(images, batch_size=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

in the './test' directory place the images you want to classify. Then use the code below to print out the predicted class for each image, the true class for each image and the filename of the image.

```
file_names=test_generator.filenames  # save list of test files names to be used later
tlabels=test_generator.labels # save test labels to be used later
class_dict=test_generator.class_indices
# code below determines test batch size and test steps
# so you go through the test images exactly once
length=len(file_names) # determine number of images
b_max=80 # set maximum batch size you will allow
test_batch_size=sorted([int(length/n) for n in range(1,length+1) if length % n ==0 and length/n<=b_max],reverse=True)[0]
test_steps=int(length/batch_size)
# make predictions
preds=model.predict(test_gen, batch_size=test_batch_size, verbose=0, steps=test_steps)
new_dict={} 
for key in class_dict: # set key in new_dict to value in class_dict and value in new_dict to key in class_dict
    value=class_dict[key]
    new_dict[value]=key
print('PREDICTED CLASS     TRUE CLASS       FILENAME            ERROR  STATUS' ) # adjust spacing based on your class names
error_list=[] # empty list to store if the prediction was correct or not
error_file_list=[]
for i, p in enumerate(preds):
    pred_index=np.argmax(p) # get the index that has the highest probability
    if pred_index == tlabels[i]:
        error_list.append ('No') # correct classification
    else:
        error_list.append('Yes')
        error_file_list.append(file_names[i])
    pred_class=new_dict[pred_index]  # find the predicted class based on the index
    true_class=new_dict[tlabels[i]] # use the test label to get the true class of the test file
    file=file_names[i]
    print(f'    {pred_class:10s}       {true_class:10s}    {file:25s}   {error_list[i]}')
```

Comment: thanks @Gerry P. but I am getting this error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'batch_outputs' referenced before assignment" from this line "   preds=model.predict(test_generator, batch_size=20, verbose=0, steps=test_steps)"

Comment: I edited my answer because it would have just shown the files with errors.  The line with the error is a line you generated. Just use the code as I provided and it should work fine.

Comment: I also modified it to add a column ERROR STATUS which is Yes if the classification is in error or No if it is correct. Also added a list error_file_list which will be a list of file names that were misclassified.